# A BFS solution to Diagonally traverse a two dimensional array

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working to solve the problem [Diagonal Traverse - LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/diagonal-traverse/)

> Given a matrix of M x N elements (M rows, N columns), return all elements of the matrix in diagonal order as shown in the below image.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> Input:
> [
>  [ 1, 2, 3 ],
>  [ 4, 5, 6 ],
>  [ 7, 8, 9 ]
> ]
>
> Output:  [1,2,4,7,5,3,6,8,9]
>
> Explanation:
> ```
>
> [image]
>
> **Note:**
>
> The total number of elements of the given matrix will not exceed 10,000.

The problem can be treated as  bfs traversing  from root (0, 0) to destination (rows, cols)

After reading  all the submissions and the discussions, I found a relatively concise solution

```
class Solution:
    def findDiagonalOrder(self, matrix: 'List[List[int]]') -> 'List[int]':
        if len(matrix) == 0:
            return []
        r, c = 0, 0
        rows, cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])
        res = []
        for _ in range(rows * cols):
            res.append(matrix[r][c])
            if (r + c) % 2 == 0:
                if c == cols - 1: #column boundary 
                    r += 1
                elif r == 0: # 
                    c += 1
                else: #move up 
                    r -= 1
                    c += 1
            else:
                if r == rows - 1: #row boundary 
                    c += 1
                elif c == 0:
                    r += 1
                else:#move down 
                    r += 1
                    c -= 1
        return res
```

I have a feeling that such a solution is not good enough, because too many labors to use multiple conditions checking.

There might be a universal solution to this pattern of problems  which could be employed later to solve the diagonal traversing problem with minimal efforts.

The problem is to travel from (0, 0) to (4, 4)

The characters:
1. the sum of each node on a diagonal equals to number of the step
2. there might be a relation formula to produce all nodes in next level from root(0,0) and the previous level.

[image]

My solution:

```
import unittest
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(levelname)s %(message)s")

class Solution:
    def findDiagonalOrder(self, matrix: 'List[List[int]]') -> 'List[int]':
        from collections import deque 
        #root is (0, 0)
        #destination is (rows, cols)
        r, c = 0, 0
        root = (r, c)
        rows, cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])  
        step = 0
        queue = deque([root]) 
        res = []

        while queue and r < rows and c < cols:
            step += 1
            size = len(queue)

            for _ in range(size):
                r, c = queue.popleft()
                res.append(matrix[r][c])

            #collect the next nodes 
            if r == 0 and c == 0: 
                c = step #(0, 1) determin the direction of the first step 
                queue.append((r,c))
                logging.debug(f"queue: {queue}")
                logging.debug(f"step: {step}, r:{r}, c: {c}")

            if c == 0:
                level = [(step-i, i) for i in range(step)]
            elif r == 0:
                level = [(i, step-i) for i in range(step)]
            queue += level 
            logging.debug(f"queue: {queue}")
            #raise Exception

        return res 

class MyCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.solution = Solution()

    def test_a(self):
        matrix = [
                    [ 1, 2, 3 ],
                    [ 4, 5, 6 ],
                    [ 7, 8, 9 ]
                ]
        answer = [1,2,4,7,5,3,6,8,9]
        check = self.solution.findDiagonalOrder(matrix)
        self.assertEqual(answer, check)

unittest.main()
```

However, it stops at

```
DEBUG queue: deque([(0, 2), (1, 1)])
DEBUG queue: deque([(0, 2), (1, 1)])
DEBUG queue: deque([(0, 2), (1, 1)])
DEBUG queue: deque([(0, 2), (1, 1)])
^CDEBUG queue: deque([(0, 2), (1, 1)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I failed to write a good relation formula to produce the nodes in next level.

Could you please provide any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is going to answer your question, but I can share my approach if its concise and clear enough for you.

The code is in C++, but you can get the idea.

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> findDiagonalOrder(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
        vector<int> result;

        int n = matrix.size();
        if(n == 0) return result;
        int m = matrix[0].size();
        if(m == 0) return result;

        result.resize(m * n);
        int row = 0, col = 0, d = 0;
        int dir[2][2] = {
               {-1, 1},
               {1, -1}
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < m * n; i++) {
            result[i] = matrix[row][col];
            row += dir[d][0];
            col += dir[d][1];

            if (row >= n) { row = n - 1; col += 2; d = 1 - d; }
            if (col >= m) { col = m - 1; row += 2; d = 1 - d; }

            if (row < 0)  { row = 0; d = 1 - d;}
            if (col < 0)  { col = 0; d = 1 - d;}
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you very muck for your C++ solution, I feel just like unexpectedly  picking up a money wallet.

Answer (score 0):

The  solution to traverse a square matrix

```
class Solution:
    def findDiagonalOrder(self, matrix: 'List[List[int]]') -> 'List[int]':
        from collections import deque 

        if(len(matrix) == 0 or len(matrix[0]) == 0):
            return []

        if(len(matrix) == 1):
            return matrix[0]

        res = []
        if(len(matrix[0]) == 1):
            for row in matrix:
                res+=row
            return res  

        r, c = 0, 0
        root = (r, c)
        rows, cols = len(matrix), len(matrix[0])  
        step = 0
        queue = deque([root]) 
        left = []
        #forwards 
        while queue and step < rows:
            step += 1
            size = len(queue)

            for _ in range(size):
                r, c = queue.popleft()
                left.append(matrix[r][c])

            if r == 0:
                level = [(i, step -i) for i in range(step+1)] #(r, c+1)
            elif c == 0:
                level = [(step-i, i) for i in range(step+1)]             
            queue += level 
            #logging.debug(f"queue: {queue}")
            #logging.debug(f"left: {left}")
            #raise Exception

        #backwords 
        step = 0
        queue = deque([root]) 
        right  = []
        #forwards 
        while queue and step < rows-1:
            step += 1
            size = len(queue)

            for _ in range(size):
                r, c = queue.popleft()
                right.append(matrix[rows-r-1][cols-c-1])

            if r == 0:
                level = [(i, step -i) for i in range(step+1)] #(r, c+1)
            elif c == 0:
                level = [(step-i, i) for i in range(step+1)]             
            queue += level 
            #logging.debug(f"queue: {queue}")
            #logging.debug(f"right: {right}")
            #raise Exception
        right.reverse()
        res = left + right 
        return res
```